# Is there a standard function in Python that takes an argument, ignores it, and always returns None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to supply a Callable returning None to a library function of the following form:

```py
def some_third_party_function(callback: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
    ...
```

but I have a function that does not return `None`

```py
def func_to_use_as_callback() -> bool:
    ...
```

and I would like to supply it to the library function in such a way that its argument is discarded.

The following attempt fails type checking, since the lambda does not return None:

```py
some_third_party_function(lambda: func_to_use_as_callback())
```

What I have at the moment is:

```py
def _discard_arg(arg) -> None:
    return None

some_third_party_function(lambda: _discard_arg(func_to_use_as_callback()))
```

Does the Python 3.10 standard library contain a function that is equivalent to `_discard_arg`? or is there some other equally concise way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: GPT4 suggested `some_third_party_function(lambda: (func_to_use_as_callback(), None)[1])` but I have no idea whether that is idiomatic, it seems ugly and inefficient to me. Is it cheaper to construct and discard a tuple, or call `_discard_arg`

Comment: What do you mean that you "would like to use a function that does not return None"? Do you want it to "always return None" or to "not return None"?

Comment: If you want to suppress the return value, you could write a decorator.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing, and you haven't replied to my earlier comment, but `lambda x: None` is a "function that takes an argument, ignores it, and always returns None."

Comment: I think `pass` as the only statement in a function isn't Pythonic unless you're not planning to use the function until you come back and change its definition. "Explicit is better than implicit", so use `return None`.

Comment: @Joe I have reworded the question to try to address your confusion. Please let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: @Joe I have taken your comment regarding `pass` into account and replaced it with `return None` thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's more clear, although I still don't know why you "would like to supply it to the library function", as opposed to `lamda x: None`, but I'll assume you have some reason.

Comment: @Joe: the real code is `cancellation_token.on_cancel(lambda: _discard_arg(task.cancel()))`. `task.cance()` (which returns a bool) needs to be supplied as the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it does, but this is easy enough to implement yourself, and what you have is fine.

However, anonymous functions are hard to track when debugging, so you might prefer to write a wrapper that takes a function and makes it return none.

```
def _discard_result(func: Callable[[], object]) -> Callable[[], None]:
    def inner() -> None:
        func()
    return inner

some_third_party_function(_discard_result(func_to_use_as_callback))
```

You can make this even better by using a class that shows what it's wrapping. And while we're here, for reusability, we can expand the wrapped function's allowed arguments.

```
from typing import ParamSpec  # New in Python 3.10

P = ParamSpec('P')

class ResultDiscarder:
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[P, object]):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """Show construction."""
        r = '{}({!r})'.format(type(self).__name__, self.func)
        return r
```

```
>>> ResultDiscarder(func_to_use_as_callback)
ResultDiscarder(<function func_to_use_as_callback at 0x7f8637c8c5e0>)
>>> # vs
>>> _discard_result(func_to_use_as_callback)
<function _discard_result.<locals>.inner at 0x7f8637eadd00>
>>> # vs
>>> lambda: _discard_arg(func_to_use_as_callback())
<function <lambda> at 0x7f8637eadd00>
```

Comment: P.S. I have a hunch that `object` should actually be `typing.Any` but I can't work out the difference at the moment.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing out the error in my code, of course I meant what you wrote, I'll update the question.

Comment: @Ross OK cool, I updated my answer. I also added another option that's even better.